# Unable to install SearchAds360Client Module

Tags: google-sa360-api

Im trying to integrate SearchAds360 google api. To download the reports. I have followed the steps provided in the google documentation "https://developers.google.com/search-ads/reporting/quickstart/quickstart-guide#python". After following all steps, I see one issue with the below module when running get_campaign.py script which retreives the all campaigns.

[image: Below screenshot shows the execution of script, throws an error. To that, i did the needfull. Yet no resolution]